# Does static class extends another class?

Tags: php, oop, reflection

I have a static class

```
class A {
    static function doMagic() { // magic }
}
```

Class B extends A:

```
class B extends A {

}
```

How can I check using php api what B is subclass of A? Something like:

```
if(B is_subclass_of A) {
    // tada
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested for php5.6:

```
<?php
$r = new ReflectionClass(B::class);
$isWeb = $r->isSubclassOf(A::class);
```

Official docs: [Reflection::isSubclassOf](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.issubclassof.php)